# Strange plant or weed?

Tags: identification, houseplants, cactus, holiday-cactus

This decided to grow in with my Christmas cactus! What is it? I have had the cactus for years. Needed to add potting soil to it, and I think that's where this came from.

Comment: Did you mean to add a photograph?

Comment: Welcome! I also wonder if you meant to include a photograph. Do you have one and it didn't post? If so, open your question using [edit]. Click on the icon that looks like a mountain. It will ask if you want to add a picture from your computer or a web address. Choose one and hit enter. If you've done that and you get an error message, let us know and we can walk you through the process! Since you're new, have a look at our [tour] and browse our [help]. [Ask] is a good place to start.  We look forward to seeing more of you!

Comment: Jill, can you give us more information please? Where do you live? Is the cactus healthy? Did you change any conditions other than adding the soil? How soon after the new soil did the visitor appear? What do its leaves look like? I don't mean to overwhelm you, but the more we know, the better we can help! For identification, we have helpful [guidelines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info).  Please [edit] in anything else you can think of! We're here to help!